# Deploying sbt project in tomcat

Tags: scala, maven, tomcat, sbt, war

I am facing an issue while deploying an sbt project which is build using maven in tomcat. 
While starting the tomcat server I am getting HTTP 500 error
While checking the logs it says 
IllegalArgument Exception: No actor system defined
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is extremely difficult to come to a conclusion with no data in hand. Can you please provide more info.

Comment: do you want me to share the pom.xml